# React Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have been following along with react basics tutorial. I'm getting this error message. I just replaced jsx transformer to babel and react.render to reactDOM.render according to some articles. What am I missing in my code?

[image]

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello world</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />), document.body);
```

Comment: Can you share your babel configuration ?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the problem is an unexpected token.

Comment: CssSY, don't forget to accept the answer that solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `)` after `HelloWorld />`

Change the line before the last from

```
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />), document.body);
```

to

```
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
```

Comment: You could have just pointed that out in the comments. It's a typographical error so you should flag and comment, refraining from answering

Comment: @AndrewL It looks like the answer to OP's problem to me.

Comment: @Roque I'm not saying it isn't, am I? I'm pointing out that he should refrain from answering a question he knew had just a typographical error.

Comment: @Roque http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions There are some others around the network that explain it clearly. Refrain from answering off-topic questions

Comment: @AndrewL StackOverflow is meant to get or give help on bugs in code. He had  a bug and couldn't recognise it, and i told him what it was. That doesn't mean his question was bad and had to be flagged, anybody can make a typo in the code and don't recognise it until someone points it out. It's kinda the point of asking, to get help, don't you think?

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo This is the part I was not sure about. But it seems that typo problems are considered off-topic as this type of question i sonly useful to the OP. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186366/how-to-flag-a-typo-question

Comment: I also believe that we should give help to those who need help with typos, *but in a more appropriate type of fashion*. By means of comments, we can point out quickly the error and they can solve it. Then you can flag the question for being off topic as this question meets the criteria of being a simple typographical error @MarcoScabbiolo

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo *StackOverflow is meant to get or give help on bugs in code.* Actually that's not only incorrect, it's the **opposite** of what it's meant to do. I suggest you read up on the goals and philosophy. If you do want to give help, then give help by suggesting ways for the people to track down their own bugs. If you want to get or give help on bugs, go find a forum or chat room or Slack channel and hang out there.